# The flask api also updates the put method but does not save it to the database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a flask api project. I want to use the User/Delete method to save the isdeleted fields = true in the database. While trying the put method in the postman, it updates it and it shows isdeleted=true, but it doesn't save it to the database. And when I get it, it returns "false".

```
@app.route('/User/Delete', methods=['PUT'])
@token_required
def delete_users(current_user):
    if 'id' in request.headers:
        id = request.headers['id']
        user = Users.query.get(id)
        user.isdeleted = True
    db.session.commit()
    return user_schema.jsonify(user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your question properly but I think you are trying to ensure that the value for isdeleted is added to your database. If so, before `db.session.commit()`, add `db.session.add(some_object)`. Your code should look like this:

```
@app.route('/User/Delete', methods=['PUT'])
@token_required
def delete_users(current_user):
    if 'id' in request.headers:
        id = request.headers['id']
        user = Users.query.get(id)
        user.isdeleted = True
        deleted_id=user.isdeleted
    db.session.add(deleted_id)
    db.session.commit()
    return user_schema.jsonify(user)
```